# Brightness control "Up"/"Down" with xrandr (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: 22.04, brightness, xrandr, backlight, tv

I am happily using the "brightness" command to control my TV as my primary display right now. But since I am working in a somewhat dim environment I was wondering if there is a way to not just set two precise values to keyboard shortcuts, but instead a more general commands for brightness "Up" and "Down"?

In the manual of xrandr I couldn't find the desired command. Perhaps I am looking for it the wrong way.

*Edit*: Here is some new info after the `inxi` command:

Graphics:
Device-1: NVIDIA GF108GLM [NVS 5200M] driver: nouveau v: kernel
Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: nouveau resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
OpenGL: renderer: NVC1 v: 4.3 Mesa 22.0.5

This is what my terminal shows, just with less colours.
Perhaps I should add that the current solution is:
`sudo xrandr --output HDMI-1 --brightness 0.7`
and
`sudo xrandr --output HDMI-1 --brightness 1`
binded to global keyboard shortcuts.

*(it's so nice to be able to organize the text just a little bit :D)*

**Edit.2**

I am not sure why, as it happened many moons ago, but I am on the open source driver because I think I had some issues with the proprietary driver. Perhaps I will stay on my working setup now as I am already used to it. Thank you for your time even if we didn't come to a solution to this not-really-a-problem thing.

Answer (score 0):

The "brightness" function is handles by the graphics drivers, not xrandr.
Depending on your hardware, the brightness may be switched via the `/sys/devices/platform/..` virtual file system.

To find the correct "switches" use the "find" command:

`find /sys/devices/platform/ -type f | grep 'brightness'`

To set a value somewhere in that tree you use:

```
echo OPTION | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/some/component/mysystembrightness
```

where OPTION and the "some/component" path is hardware specific.

**Edit**

Your `inxi` reveals a NVIDIA graphics card with nouveau driver. Try to install the proprietary NVIDIA driver, which supports brightness control better.

After you installed the NVIDIA drivers do:

`sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/21-nvidia.conf`

Paste the following into the file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"   
EndSection
```

Additionally add to your grub commandline:
`acpi_backlight=vendor`

update_grub and reboot.

Comment: I can clearly see I am getting a lot of things wrong, but so far it's working for me.
The "find" command brings me some of those lines:   
`/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::capslock/brightness`                     
`/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::capslock/max_brightness`

Comment: _(meh, I can't even format this right)_

Comment: Not in comments. You did a pretty good, but adding it to your question would've been better, since no one wants to browse through the comments to get **all** information. But you seem to have no relevant brightness control there -this is all keyboard/led stuff. Could you execute `inxi -G`and paste the output into your question? (where you can format it)

Comment: See my updated answer. Report back if it worked